# Пишу сайт на laravel .Как организовать сохранении фотографий если пользователи скидывают разных размеров плюс вертикальные

Tags: php, laravel, изображения

В дизайне есть размер 320х300 но если обрезать все фото то некоторые становятся очень растянутими. И как понять если изображение вертикально что его надо перевернуть .Есть ли у кого опыт реализации на php?

```
if (isset($request->upload_mean)) {
          $image=$request->upload_mean;
              $currentData = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imagename =$currentData . '-' . uniqid() . '-' .$image>getClientOriginalName(); 

            $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(360, 320, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();                 
            });

            $img->stream(); // <-- Key point

            Storage::disk('public')->put('post/' . $imagename, $img);
            //Storage::disk('local')->put('images/1/smalls'.'/'.$fileName, $img, 'public');


                $imageMNameDb.=$imagename;
      }
        if (isset($request->upload)) {
            foreach($request->upload as $image ){
            //уникальное имя для изображения
            $currentData = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imagename =$currentData . '-' . uniqid() . '-' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            //проверка директории
            if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('post')) {
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('post');
            }
            //resize image
           // $postImg = Image::make($image)->save($imagename, 30);
            //Storage::disk('public')->put('post/' . $imagename, $postImg);
             $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(320, 300, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();                 
            });

            $img->stream(); // <-- Key point

            Storage::disk('public')->put('post/' . $imagename, $img);
            //Storage::disk('local')->put('images/1/smalls'.'/'.$fileName, $img, 'public');


                $imageNameDb.=$imagename.';';
            }
            }
        else {
            $imagename = "default.png";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если программно, то можно так:

```php
$image = "img/Вертикальная.jpg"; // Получаем путь картинки.
$size = getimagesize ($image); //Получаем размеры картинки.
$width = $size[0]; // Получаем ширину. Специально написал отдельно для наглядности.
$height = $size[1]; // Получаем высоту.

if ($height > $width){ // Если высота картинки больше ширины, значит картинка вертикальная.
    $new_image = 'img/Горизонтальная.jpg';
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);    // Картинка
    $degrees = 90;                         //Наклон картинки
    $imgR = imagerotate($img, $degrees, 0); // Поворачиваем
    imagejpeg($imgR, $new_image, 90); //Перерисовываем в новую, чтобы сохранить на сервере. Если этого не требуется, тогда $imgR
}

echo "<img src=img/Горизонтальная.jpg>";
echo "<img src=img/Вертикальная.jpg>";
```

Результат:
Горизонтальная.jpg
 [image: horizontal]

Вертикальная.jpg
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Есть специальный пакет intervention/image в Laravel. И вот сайт http://image.intervention.io/api/rotate. Думаю поможет вам.